# useEffect not working saving data in my local storage when I refresh my page of the todo list

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and creating my first react app. not sure why the todo list is not saved even though I have used localStorage set and get methods. I am also getting error about the key in my map method. I can't seen to find any issues on my own with the code.Below is the code of the todo list App

```
import TodoList from "./TodoList";
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid'

function App() {
 const [todos,setTodos] = useState([{}]);
 const inputRef = useRef();

 const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "todoapp"

 useEffect(() =>{
  const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
  if(storedTodos){
    setTodos(storedTodos)} 
  }, [])
 
 useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY,JSON.stringify(todos))
  }, [todos])
 

function toggleTodo(id){
  const newTodos= [...todos]
const todo = newTodos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
todo.complete = !todo.complete
setTodos(newTodos)
}

 function handleAdd(e) {
 const name = inputRef.current.value;
 if(name === "")return 
 setTodos(prevTodos => {
    return [...prevTodos,{id:uuid(),name:name,complete:false}]
 })

 inputRef.current.value = null;
  }
 
function handleClearTodos(){
const newTodos = todos.filter(todo=>!todo.complete)
setTodos(newTodos)
}
  


  return (
  <>
  <h1>Chores!!</h1>
    <TodoList todo={todos} toggleTodo ={toggleTodo} />
  <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
  <button onClick ={handleAdd}>Add todo</button>
  <button onClick={handleClearTodos}>Clear todo </button>
  <div> {todos.filter(todo => !todo.complete).length} left todo</div>
       
</>
  )

  }
export default App;
```

```
import Todo from './Todo'

export default function TodoList({todo,toggleTodo}) {
  return (
todo.map((todo)=> {
return <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo} />
})
  )
}
```

Comment: You clear the data on load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY,JSON.stringify(todos))
  }, [todos])
```

Is probably taking the initial state of `todos` on the first render (empty array) and overwriting what data was in their with that initial state.

You might think the previous effect counters this since `todos` is populated from local storage -- but it doesn't, because on that initial render pass, the second effect will only see the *old* value of `todos`. This seems counter-intuitive at first. But it's because whenever you call a set state operation, it doesn't actual change the value of `todos` immediately, it waits until the render passes, and then it changes for the next render. I.e. it is, in a way, "queued".

For the local storage `setItem`, you probably want to do it in the event handler of what manipulates the `todos` and not in an effect. [See the React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#should-this-code-move-to-an-event-handler).

```
import TodoList from "./TodoList";
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid'

function App() {
 const [todos,setTodos] = useState([{}]);
 const inputRef = useRef();

 const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "todoapp"

 const storeTodos = (todos) => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY,JSON.stringify(todos))
    setTodos(todos)
 }

 useEffect(() =>{
  const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
  if(storedTodos){
    setTodos(storedTodos)} 
  }, [])
 

function toggleTodo(id){
  const newTodos= [...todos]
const todo = newTodos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
todo.complete = !todo.complete
storeTodos(newTodos)
}

 function handleAdd(e) {
 const name = inputRef.current.value;
 if(name === "")return 
 storeTodos(prevTodos => {
    return [...prevTodos,{id:uuid(),name:name,complete:false}]
 })

 inputRef.current.value = null;
  }
 
function handleClearTodos(){
const newTodos = todos.filter(todo=>!todo.complete)
storeTodos(newTodos)
}
  


  return (
  <>
  <h1>Chores!!</h1>
    <TodoList todo={todos} toggleTodo ={toggleTodo} />
  <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
  <button onClick ={handleAdd}>Add todo</button>
  <button onClick={handleClearTodos}>Clear todo </button>
  <div> {todos.filter(todo => !todo.complete).length} left todo</div>
       
</>
  )

  }
export default App;
```

As the for the key error, we'd need to see the code in `TodoList`, but you need to ensure when you map over them, that the `id` property of each todo is passed to a `key` prop on the top most element/component within the map callback.

Comment: awesome, it worked . The Todolist component is at the bottom of the code snippet above.